# Auto Layout in IB: How do I set a subview of a view controller's main view to resize to its superview size?

Tags: ios7, interface-builder, autolayout

Seems like a no-brainer but I just can't get this bare-bones setup right!
Mind you, I don't want to add constraints via code but rather do it all thru IB:

1. One view Controller in a Sttoryboard with its main view and a collection view as a child of the main view
2. I want to set it up such that when the view controller is loaded, its main view resizes to the device screen size (3.5 vs 4, so 320 x 480 vs 320 x 568). And the collection view should also resize to take up the whole area defined by its parent view.

What I did:

1. created a new Storyboard with a new view controller with a main view
2. created the collection view as a child of the main view.
3. set the collection view's size to the same size as its parent in IB (which at editing time is the 4 inch format).
4. I set the collection view's leading, top, trailing, and bottom constraints to 0 with respect to the superview. I'd assume this means "resize to whatever you need to so that the spacing constraints hold," which since they are all 0, would imply resizing to fit the whole superview area.
5. In the view controller code, I make sure it does its thing with the collection view as far as datasource / delegate. That is, the collection view is loading up cells and the content size's height is always larger than the device screen, so regardless of the collection view being full screen, there's always going to be content to scroll.

**What I'd expect:**
On app start and view load, both the view controller's main view and its child, the collection view, should be either 320x480 or 320x568, depending on the device screen size.

**What actually happens:**
On app start and view load, the view controller's main view resizes to 320x480, but the collection view is stuck at 320x568, which is the design-time size I gave it in IB.

I also get constraints conflicts:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xed66060 V:[UICollectionView:0x13a79400]-(-548)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xed65c90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xed66090 V:[UICollectionView:0x13a79400]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xed65da0]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xed4d4e0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xed65c90]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xed65c00 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xed65730 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xed65da0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xed651f0 _UILayoutGuide:0xed65da0.bottom == UIView:0xed65c00.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xed72ee0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0xed65c00(480)]>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES probably for your top level(main) view and this is creating additional constraints automatically which is conflicting with the constraints created in Interface builder. Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO for your main view and let us know how it goes.

Comment: But isn't `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` supposed to be automatically set to `NO` if the view controller and views are all created inside a Storyboard with Autolayout enabled?

Comment: It is set to YES for the root view by default. Check this mailing list query and answer [link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Feb/msg00498.html)